# Query if server is participating in an availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

Is there a way to query whether a server is participating in an availability group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
AG.name AS [Name],
ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [PrimaryReplicaServerName],
ISNULL(arstates.role, 3) AS [LocalReplicaRole]
FROM master.sys.availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
    ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.availability_replicas AS AR
    ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
    ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local = 1
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

please see this link for more info..

https://www.pythian.com/blog/list-of-sql-server-databases-in-an-availability-group/

Answer (score 3):

When a server instance is having AlwaysON turned on, you can confirm by `SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled') = 1`

Then you can use [below query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131636/8783) if you want to get more detail :

```
--- get data into temp tables 

select * into #availability_groups from sys.availability_groups
select * into #availability_replicas from sys.availability_replicas

SELECT  
ISNULL(agstates.primary_replica, '') AS [Primary_AG_Server],
dbcs.database_name AS [DatabaseName]
 ,ar.replica_server_name as [Secondary_AG_Servers]

   FROM #availability_groups AS AG
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states as agstates
   ON AG.group_id = agstates.group_id
INNER JOIN #availability_replicas AS AR
   ON AG.group_id = AR.group_id
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS arstates
   ON AR.replica_id = arstates.replica_id AND arstates.is_local <> 1 -- is_local is not 1 .. so we get secondary server names
INNER JOIN master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states AS dbcs
   ON arstates.replica_id = dbcs.replica_id
    group by agstates.primary_replica, dbcs.database_name, ar.replica_server_name
```

**Note**: If you have servers that are mixed - some using AlwaysON and some not, then you will need to use dynamic sql else above query will fail on the ones that are not configured to use AlwaysON.